# How do I test Facebook login on Android?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to write two behavior-driven test verifying that I can reach two states of my Android app, after Facebook authentication: a "login failed" view, and the normal app view.

I've followed the [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) steps. Login works fine when I launch the app from Eclipse. I can manually test my "login failed" screen by hitting Back when I'm logged out and the FB auth view launches. The goal here is to automate that.

I've tried writing this test with Robolectric and Robotium. Robolectric throws a permissions exception when the FB activity tries to launch.

Robotium is more successful: it can at least launch the LoginActivity. But the Solo object only knows about my app's activities and doesn't recognize the Facebook activity, so calling `solo.goBack()` calls Back on my MainActivity, ending the test.

This is a new project and I'm happy to use a different library. What is the best way to test Facebook login in an app?